# Extending Surface3D with C++ loses visual parent

Tags: qt, qml

I am extending Surface3D [using this technique](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.10/qtqml-cppintegration-definetypes.html#registering-extension-objects)  with a C++ class called Surface3DExtension. Surface3DExtension class defines a single property called “topoFile”, and contains a pointer to the “standard” Q3DSurface, per the technique referenced above:

```
    class Surface3DExtension : public QObject
    {
       Q_OBJECT
       Q_PROPERTY(QString topoFile READ getTopoFile WRITE setTopoFile NOTIFY topoFileChanged)

    public:
       explicit Surface3DExtension(QObject *parent);

       int getTopoFile();
       void setTopoFile(QString topoFile);


    signals:
       void topoFileChanged();

    public slots:

    private:
       // Actual Q3DSurface instance
       Q3DSurface *m_surface;

};
```

I display the Surface3D with this qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtDataVisualization 1.2
import MyTest.test 1.0  // My Surface3D extension

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    title: "Basic layouts"
    property int margin: 11
    width: mainLayout.implicitWidth + 2 * margin
    height: mainLayout.implicitHeight + 2 * margin
    minimumWidth: mainLayout.Layout.minimumWidth + 2 * margin
    minimumHeight: mainLayout.Layout.minimumHeight + 2 * margin

    ColumnLayout {
        id: mainLayout
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: margin
        GroupBox {
            id: rowBox
            title: "Row layout"
            Layout.fillWidth: true

            RowLayout {
                id: rowLayout
                anchors.fill: parent
                Surface3D {
                    objectName: "mySurface"
                    // parent: rowLayout
                    width: 640
                    height: 480
                    visible: true
                    topoFile: "myfile"
                }
                Button {
                    text: "Button"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

If the qml file does NOT import my extended Surface3D type, Surface3D is displayed as expected within the main application window. However when main.qml imports my extended Surface3D type, the Surface3D appears in a separate borderless window. Debugging the C++ code shows that m_surface->getParent() returns nullptr, i.e. has no visual parent. How can fix this?

Thanks
Tom

Comment: It seems that the problem of using the type Q3DSurface from inside QML cannot be solved. The problem is: Q3DSurface is derived from QAbstract3DGraph which is derived from QWindow. It is not QML item or QQuickItem which can be embedded as part of QML nested item structure. The normal way to use that thing: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdatavisualization-surface-example.html

Comment: @AlexanderV: But how is it then, that if his extension is not imported, it works inside of QML? https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtdatavisualization-surface3d.html - You are right, that at least the docs don't know an Item as supertype, but apparently (also how it is used in the documentation) it acts like one. At least unless you try to extend it...

Comment: @derM: I am confused, for instance where is property "width" of QML Surface3D  documented? The pattern with QML is to expect Item type with that? It all makes us want to look at that class source code then. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtdatavisualization-surface3d-members.html

Comment: @AlexanderV:  When my Surface3DExtended C++ constructor is called, the input object is of type Q3DSurface, as expected from the description at https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.10/qtqml-cppintegration-definetypes.html#registering-extension-objects. You are right, I do not see "width" or "height" documented - but setting those properties on Surface3D certainly does affect the size. I'm finding that much of the Qt documentation is kind of infuriatingly vague and incomplete ;-)

Comment: To make it even more “interesting”... My qml assigns objectName “mySurface” to the Surface3D item. If my qml does NOT import my extension then after main() loads the qml, rootObject->findChildren() finds an object named “mySurface” of type DataVisualization.DeclarativeSurface. Nowhere can I find documentation for DeclarativeSurface. If qml DOES import my extension then the “mySurface” object is of type Q3DSurface - but invoking Q3DSurface::parent() returns null - i.e. no visual parent, so displayed in its own borderless window. How can I assign a visual parent to the mySurface object from C++?

Comment: With Qt3D (unsure if that is relevant at all) we have 2 types of parents for the class object can be applied: QObject (Qt hierarchy) and QNode (Qt3D visual items hierarchy) and that causes "issues". I force resolve the type of parent by casting to either to be sure when trying setParent() etc. Oh... and I went to docs and see `parent() const : QWindow *` on https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/q3dsurface-members.html.